# Как сделать выполнение циклов одновременным и ускорить код в разы?

Tags: python, многопоточность, оптимизация

У меня есть код, в котором **`8`** циклов. Каждые два цикла обрабатывают один словарь данных, в данном примере список. 
Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы каждая пара циклов вычислялась одновременно, при этом, чтобы каждая пара циклов выдавала результат одновременно, чтобы не было такого, что одна пара выдаёт результат раньше другой.

И второй момент.

Как ускорить код? Есть какие-то действенные способы. Я пробовал основы многопоточности, но код становился только медленнее. Скорее всего делал что-то не то.

Для примера даю простейшие циклы, мои рабочие циклы гораздо сложнее по вычислению, но их дать вам не могу. (конфиденциальность).

```
data1 = [5, 6, 7, 3, 5 , 8, 3]
for i in data1:
    if i == 3:
        data1[i] = 9
print(data1)
for i in data1:
    if i == 2:
        data1[i] = 5
print(data1)

data2 = [5, 6, 7, 3, 5 , 8, 3]
for i in data2:
    if i == 8:
        data1[i] = 9
print(data2)
for i in data1:
    if i == 5:
        data2[i] = 00
print(data2)

data3 = [5, 6, 7, 3, 5 , 8, 3]
for i in data3:
    if i == 5:
        data3[i] = 9
print(data3)
for i in data3:
    if i == 1:
        data3[i] = 5
print(data3)

data4 = [5, 6, 7, 3, 5 , 8, 3]
for i in data4:
    if i == 3:
        data4[i] = 5
print(data4)
for i in data4:
    if i == 2:
        data4[i] = 9
print(data4)
```

Заранее всем спасибо за потраченное на мой вопрос время.

Comment: Если у вас нет операций ввода-вывода, то вам многопроцессное вычисление надо (если надо), а не многопотоковое.  Это ответит на оба вопроса. Но почему вам надо "чтобы не было такого, что одна пара выдаёт результат раньше другой."? Чуть раньше - можно? Абсолютной синхронности трудно достичь.

Comment: Можно сделать через `multiprocessing.Pool` довольно просто, но проблема в том, что данные нужно ещё передать в другой поток и получить потом обратно, при этом данные сериализуются и десериализуются, что может съесть всю выгоду. Поэтому не зная, как вы получаете данные и куда их потом деваете, тут сложно советовать что-то конкретное.

Comment: Ладно, допустим, что мне не нужна синхронность, а просто увеличение скорости кода, что вы в этом случае могли бы посоветовать?

Comment: Да как-раз синхронность то через `Pool` получается элементарно. Вы хотя бы скажите какого размера у вас примерно эти массивы и откуда вы их берёте и куда деваете. Если читаете из файлов и потом обратно в файлы кладёте, то это идеально для мультипроцессинга, если всё это делать именно в отдельных процессах - чтение, обработку, запись. А если в памяти всё должно лежать одновременно, то дело плохо и надо ещё думать.

Comment: Вообще, если массивы именно числовые и вычисления достаточно простые, то есть вероятность, что достаточно обернуть ваш код в декоратор `numba.njit` и всё будет работать в 10 раз быстрее прямо сразу и ничего с ним делать вообще больше не нужно, `numba` сама сделает и потоки и прочую оптимизацию. Но сработает это не всегда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Внимание**: В примере у меня работа с `numpy.array`, а с чисто питоновскими списками всё будет несколько сложнее. Но в любом случае вам лучше будет смотреть в сторону типизированных массивов для ускорения расчётов, родные типы питона довольно тормозные. Если только вам не нужно работать с бесконечными `int`-ами, тогда у родного `int` питона есть преимущество.

---

Если у вас обычные числа в списках и довольно простые ветвления и вычисления, то может помочь `Numba` причём без особых усилий:

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

def process1(data1):
    for i in data1:
        if i == 3:
            data1[i] = 9
    for i in data1:
        if i == 2:
            data1[i] = 5
    return data1

data1 = np.random.randint(100, size=(10_000_000))
%time process1(data1)

p1 = nb.njit(process1)
%time p1(data1)

print()
```

Вывод:

```
CPU times: user 6.43 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 6.43 s
Wall time: 6.45 s
CPU times: user 224 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 224 ms
Wall time: 224 ms
```

Список из 10 млн. элементов обычный питон обрабатывает 6 секунд, а после использования декоратора `numba.njit` тот же список и тем же самым кодом обрабатывается 0.2 секунды, ускорение в 30 раз без малейших усилий. Причём, чем больше размеры списков, тем заметнее будет ускорение.

Но если вычисления будут не просто арифметические и условия будут не такие простые, то с `Numba` возможно придётся ещё повозиться, чтобы она согласилась ускорять ваш код.

Answer (score 0):

Я сам занимаюсь олимпиадным программированием. Когда-то мне в голову пришла мысль, что можно код ускорить с помощью многопоточности, но это не дало результатов. Для ускорения программы используют методы [динамического программирования](https://dou.ua/lenta/columns/about-dynamic-programming/), например, мемоизация. Также вместо обычного компилятора Python 3, можно использовать PyPy, он быстрее. 
Насчет 8 циклов.
Я для многопоточности использую модуль `Thread`.  Вот как он работает:

```
def func(d):
    for i in range(d):
        print(i)
Thread.start_new_thread(func, (9))
```

Вообще, мне кажется, что два потока будут конфликтовать между собой, если они будут менять один массив. Поэтому, если вам надо проводить какие-то большие операции на миллионы чисел, то советую использовать C++

Comment: Да, при работе с одним массивом `GIL` будет мешать. С разными - надо пробовать.

Comment: Да еще и с компиляцией в exe проблемы возникнуть могут. Лучше какой-то кусок кода обернуть в C++ и использовать его, передавая из Python скрипта аргументы

Comment: Странный какой-то комментарий: " Когда-то мне в голову пришла мысль, что можно код ускорить с помощью многопоточности, но это не дало результатов." Все зависит от того, какой код. Без конкретики фраза смысла не несет.